# How to manage database and transaction status for shopify billing api?

Tags: shopify-app

I am developing shopify app. but confused in managing database for billing records and payment status. I don't know that I should manage each transaction's entry in database or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer ,

we don't need to manage database for payment status or billing records ,shopify will automatically handle it. we just need shop domain and access token.and if needed any information about billing then we can make a api call

"GET /admin/recurring_application_charges.json"

for more on this read this conversation

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/shopify-charging-for-our-app-flow-using-billing-api-397909